# Using mathematical induction to prove a generalized form of DeMorgan's Law for sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, induction

My textbook has the following diagram which illustrates a mathematical induction proof of DeMorgan's Law for sets, but I'm having trouble understanding why the approach they've outlined here is correct. I note my issue below the diagram.

[image]

My confusion lies in the step which reads as the complement of $B$ union with the complement of $A_{k+1}$ and annotated in red as "DeMorgans's Law". Isn't this circular reasoning? Am I misunderstanding something? I've got inductive reasoning down, and I know how/why it works, but I'm struggling to extend it to sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not circular reasoning because they have already proven the DeMorgan's Law involving two sets, and they use that to help prove the Generalized DeMorgan's Law. Indeed, in the step you indicate where they use the DeMorgan's Law they apply it to *two* sets: $B$ and $A_{k+1}$, so that is perfectly valid.

Maybe you are worried about the fact that $B$ is defined as the intersection of $k$ sets $A_1$ through $A_k$? Well, first of all, that does not take away from the fact that $B$ is still *one* set, and second, they don't apply the DeMorgan's rule over those sets $A_1$ through $A_k$ at the time of that step ... They do that later using the inductive hypothesis.

In short: DeMorgan's Law $\not =$ Generalized DeMorgan's Law

Answer (score 1):

It is not a circular reasoning.

I assume that De Morgan's law (for two sets) is previously proved in your text. And the proof you pasted here is that of *Generalized* De Morgan's law, which is for any finite number of sets.

Comment: The book proved DeMorgan's law for sets using the definition of $x$ being in sets $A$ and $B$, and I understood how that works and why it extends to sets. I just wasn't sure if what they did here was circular reasoning or not. any particular reason why what they did is "legal"?

Comment: @AleksandrH The main idea behind the proof is, "If we know it works for *two* sets, we can show it works for any (finite) number of sets" So as pointed out in this answer, **if** the book has shown that $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ (where there are only two sets here), then induction is a way to formalize the idea that, "If we can do it for two sets (as we've already proven), we just do that as many times as necessary, to make sure the analogous statement holds for $n$ sets."

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not circular reasoning, because we are applying De Morgan's law to the case where $n=2$ (i.e. the usual De' Morgan's law), and we have established that case. I suppose in the proof they could have said let $k \geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   \overline{A \cap B \cap C \cap D \cap E}
   &= \overline{(A \cap B \cap C \cap D)} \cup \overline{E}\\
   &= \overline{(A \cap B \cap C)} \cup \overline D \cup \overline E \\
   &= \overline{(A \cap B)} \cup \overline C \cup \overline D \cup \overline E \\
   &= \overline A \cup \overline B \cup \overline C \cup \overline D \cup \overline E
\end{align}